# nodeJS, moving a file to a new folder

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to move an existing file into a new folder that  doesn't exist. I tried:

```
var source = fs.createReadStream(file.thumbnail.path);
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('./public/uploads/'+ user._id + '/' + file.myfail.name);

source.pipe(dest);
```

However, I keep getting this error `Error: ENOENT, open './public/uploads/553283d3216c3895055612dd/18f1b232024ac9d7a5d398dc9291e160.jpg'`

I also tried using `__dirname` but it doesn't seem to help.

I'm pretty sure it's a non-existant folder issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

PS: after checking if the folder doesn't exist, how do I create it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ENOENT` error is because the file or folder does not exist.

The only way to get around this problem is to open a file that does exist. Perhaps the user's folder does not exist before you try this operation? Check to see if the folder exists.

Another thing to note is that Node.js has a [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module that provides a lot of useful filepath tools.

```
var path = require( 'path' )
var destination = path.join( __dirname, 'public/uploads', user._id, file.myfile.name )
```

Comment: and how do I create the folder in case it not exist ?

Comment: `fs.mkdir` - alternatively you can use the npm `mkdirp` if you're making a directory whose parents may not exist

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check if the sub-directory "./public/uploads/" + user._id exists.

If it doesn't exist create the directory before attempting to write out to a directory that doesn't exist.